# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0.31818181 0.40082645 0.49173555 ... 0.14049587 0.14876033 0.15289256]

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        data, target, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from scipy.stats import sem

def evaluate_cross_validation(clf, X, y, K):
    # create a k-fold cross validation iterator
    cv = KFold( K , shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    # by default the score used is the one returned by score method of the estimator (accuracy)
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=cv)
    print (scores)
    print ("Mean score: {0:.3f} (+/-{1:.3f})".format(
        np.mean(scores), sem(scores)))
evaluate_cross_validation(svc_1, X_train, y_train, 5)
from sklearn import metrics

def train_and_evaluate(clf, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print ("Accuracy on training set:")
    print (clf.score(X_train, y_train))
    print ("Accuracy on testing set:")
    print (clf.score(X_test, y_test))

    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    print ("Classification Report:")
    print (metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print ("Confusion Matrix:")
    print (metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
train_and_evaluate(svc_1, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

random_image_button = Button(description="New image!")

def display_face_and_prediction(b):
    index = randint(0, 400)
    face = faces.images[index]
    display_face(face)
    print("this person is smiling: {0}".format(svc_1.predict(faces.data[index, :])==1))

random_image_button.on_click(display_face_and_prediction)
display(random_image_button)
display_face_and_prediction(0)
```

when i ran the code beginning from `random_image_button = Button(description="New image!")`, it gives me the error below:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0.31818181
>   0.40082645 0.49173555 ... 0.14049587 0.14876033 0.15289256]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
>   feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: @gmds how can i fix this error?

Comment: It literally asks you to reshape it to 2D. Have you tried that?

Comment: @gmds , i did a reshape to X_test, X_train, y_train and y_test, and it didn't work

Comment: @gmds ,  i did this :                                                                               X_train= X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1)

Comment: Then you need to think about where you're getting your training and test data from. Look at the signature of the `fit` method for `sklearn` estimators: `X: (n_samples, n_features)`. Each row should represent a sample and each column a feature. If you have a 1D array, then it is of the wrong shape. Don't reshape blindly! *Read the documentation and understand what each method expects*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has problem in here :

```
def display_face_and_prediction(b):
index = randint(0, 400)
face = faces.images[index]
display_face(face)
print("this person is smiling: {0}".format(svc_1.predict(faces.data[index, :])==1))
```

you model need to fid 2d array to predict yet you fit faces.data[index,:]
you can reshape your faces.data[index,:] to 2d array

Comment: i did this: `print("this person is smiling: {0}".format(svc_1.predict(faces.data[index, :])==1).reshape(-1,1))`, still didn't work

Comment: oh now it worked, i used this : `print("this person is smiling: {0}".format(svc_1.predict(faces.data[index, :].reshape(1,-1))==1))`, thank you so much @joyzaza